# Why doesn't sizeof work as expected?

Tags: c, printf, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{   
    printf("%d", sizeof (getchar()) );
}
```

What I expect is,
1. Type input.
2. Read input and return input value.
3. Evaluate sizeof value.
4. Print the sizeof value.

But the first step never happens.

Why doesn't the first step happen?

Comment: I get this: [ics@steamboy ics_client]$ gcc -o temp temp.c
[ics@steamboy ics_client]$ ./temp
4[ics@steamboy ics_client]$ What platform are you on?

Comment: Also you should add a `\n' at the end of you format string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator does not evaluate its operand unless its type is a variable length array type: It looks at the type and returns the size. This is perfectly safe:

```
char *ptr = NULL; // NULL ponter!
printf("%zu", sizeof *ptr);
```

It will return `1`, since it does not have to evaluate the expression to know the answer.

Comment: "This is perfectly safe:" --> not really.  The result type of `sizeof` is `size_t`.    A matching `printf()` specifier is `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`.

Answer (score 2):

> What I expect is, 1. Type input. 2. Read input and return input value. 3. Evaluate sizeof value 4. Print the sizeof value.
>
> But the first step never happens. Why doesn't the first step happen?

Because, with a very few exceptions, the `sizeof` operator does not evaluate its operand.  Your usage is not one of the exceptions.  Not evaluating `getchar()` means `getchar()` is not called.

In any event, I'm not sure what you expect from your code.  Even if `getchar()` *were* called, the result always has the same type (`int`), which does not depend on the input.

Do also pay attention to @P.P.'s comments.  Your `printf()` format does not match the type of the data being printed, `size_t`.  As he observes, the `printf()` call has undefined behavior as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`getchar()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) return type is an `int`, not a `char`. `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform.

Also, you should use `%zu` to print `size_t` values. Using incorrect format specifier is technically [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

In C the sizeof operator is evaluated at run-time only for Variable Size Arrays (VLA). In all other cases the operator does nor evaluate its operand. It deduces the type of the expression and returns the size of object of the deduced type.